# Can anyone explain this PHP code using json_encode and json_decode?

Tags: php, json

```
  $a = '{ "tag": "<b></b>" }';
  echo json_encode( json_decode($a) );
```

This outputs:

```
{"tag":"<b><\/b>"}
```

when you would think it would output exactly the input.  For some reason json_encode adds an extra slash.

Comment: You can't really assume that your JSON string is correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because it's part of the JSON standard

http://json.org/

> char
>
> ```
> any-Unicode-character-
>     except-"-or-\-or-
>     control-character
> \"
> \\
> \/ <---- see here?
> \b
> \f
> \n
> \r
> \t
> \u four-hex-digits
> ```

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
echo json_encode($a,JSON_HEX_TAG)
```

Result will be:

```
["\u003C\u003E"]
```

You can read this article to improve your knowledge about JSON_ENCODE
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 2):

That's probably a security-feature. The escaped version (Eg. the output) would be parsed as similar to the unescaped-version, by Javascript (Eg. `\/` becomes `/`). Having escaped the slash like that, there is a lesser chance of the browser misinterpreting the Javascript-string as HTML. Of course, if you treat the data correct, this shouldn't be needed, so it's more a safeguard against a clueless programmer messing things up for himself.

Answer (score 2):

Your input is not valid JSON, but PHP's JSON parser (like most JSON parsers) will parse it anyway.

Comment: I believe the extra whitespace outside of your string should not be there.