# json unwanted slashes

Tags: php, json

```
$test = json_encode(array("test"=>"test / test"));
echo $test;
```

output: {"test":"test \/ test"}

Why ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127739/can-anyone-explain-this-php-code-using-json-encode-and-json-decode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's [correct JSON](http://json.org/). It also helps when embedding e.g. `</script>` in JavaScript embedded in HTML.

Comment: You don't *need* to escape `/` though.  The backslash is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the way json_encode encode! If you do json_decode() on that string the escape char will have disappeared.
I'd suggest you use the JSON stringifier and parser if you want to be 100% sure of the compatibility between what json_encode outputs and what JS reads.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js